# multiple events not created in icalendar

Tags: events, icalendar, caldav

My Request is :

```
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    VERSION:2.0
    PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iCal 5.0.2//EN
    BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
    TZID:UTC
    BEGIN:STANDARD
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20140101
    TZNAME:UTC
    TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
    TZOFFSETTO:+0000
    END:STANDARD
    END:VTIMEZONE
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    ATTENDEE;CN=Isha;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:MAILTO:iagarwal@sch
     eduleonce.com
    DESCRIPTION:meeting details0
    DTEND;TZID=UTC:20150601T061500
    DTSTAMP:20150520T073543Z
    DTSTART;TZID=UTC:20150601T051500
    SEQUENCE:0
    STATUS:Confirmed
    SUMMARY:meeting 10
    TRANSP:Opaque
    UID:6BBD518F-B0E3-4157-A105-A7ECEB82D73E
    END:VEVENT
 BEGIN:VEVENT
    ATTENDEE;CN=Isha;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:MAILTO:iagarwal@sch
     eduleonce.com
    DESCRIPTION:meeting details1
    DTEND;TZID=UTC:20150601T061500
    DTSTAMP:20150520T073543Z
    DTSTART;TZID=UTC:20150601T051500
    SEQUENCE:0
    STATUS:Confirmed
    SUMMARY:meeting 11
    TRANSP:Opaque
    UID:6BBD518F-B0E3-4157-A105-A7ECEB82D73F
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR
```

URL : https://p22-caldav.icloud.com/XXX/calendars/home
Method: POST
Depth:1

The web response does not return any exception. In web response I get http status code as "OK" but the event is not created on my icloud calendar.

I refered to [enter link description here](https://svn.calendarserver.org/repository/calendarserver/CalendarServer/trunk/doc/Extensions/calendarserver-bulk-change.txt) . Search for Example: Calendar Resource Bulk Create

Comment: Probably just a copy/paste error, but the entity in the question lacks the END:VCALENDAR at the end?

Comment: Also, for UTC you don't need to define a timezone. Just add a 'Z' to the date/time values (like 20150601T061500Z).

Answer (score 1):

Your POST request is on the calendar *home* which is the parent collection of actual calendars. I think you want to do the POST on one of your actual calendar.

https://p22-caldav.icloud.com/XXX/calendars/home/xxxx/

- You have events with ATTENDEE property but no ORGANIZER property.

Comment: Yes i am posting it on home calendar. I want to add multiple meetings on that calendar. Even if i set ORGANIZER property , then also its not showing meeting in icloud.

Comment: Do you mean that we cant make events on HOME calendar ?

Comment: The CalDAV protocol states that the calendar home can be either a calendar collection itself (i.e. you can create events in it) or the parent of calendar collections. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4791#section-6.2.1 .  In practice though, most servers do *not* support creating events in the calendar home. Please note that I'm not talking about a calendar called HOME but about the calendar home, which is the parent container for all calendars.

Comment: even if I post my events to other calendars , same issue is happening. Events are not created but response is returned as "OK"